# Convergence of the improper integral $\int_0^1\frac{\tan(x)\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{x^5}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, improper-integrals

> I want to examine whether or not the improper integral $$\int_0^1\dfrac{\tan(x)\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{x^5}}dx$$ converges.

My work:

I wanted to use the following corollary:

> Let $f,g:[a,+\infty)$ be two positive functions which are Riemann-integrable on every closed interval $[a,b], b>a$. Suppose there is a limit in $\overline{\Bbb R}$:
> $$L:=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\in[0,+\infty].$$
> If the improper integral $\int\limits_a^{+\infty}g(x)dx$ converges and $L\in[0,+\infty),$ then the improper integral $\int\limits_a^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ converges.
>
> If the improper integral $\int_a^{+\infty} g(x)dx$ diverges and $c\in(0,+\infty],$ the improper integral also diverges.

Since, in the given example, $x\in(0,1],$ I decided to do a substitution $x=\frac1t\implies dx=-\frac{dt}{t^2}\implies dt=-t^2dx.$ I got the following:
$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^1\frac{\tan(x)\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{x^5}}dx&=-\int_{+\infty}^1\tan\left(\frac1t\right)\ln\left(1+\frac1t\right)\sqrt t(-t^2dx)\\&=\int_1^{+\infty}\tan\left(\frac1t\right)\ln\left(1+\frac1t\right)\sqrt tdt.\end{aligned}$$

Then I saw:
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\tan\left(\frac1t\right)\ln\left(1+\frac1t\right)\sqrt t}{\frac1t\cdot\frac1t\cdot \sqrt t}=1$$

In the denominator, we have $t^{1/2-2}$ and
$$\int_1^{+\infty}t^{1/2-2}dt=-2\frac1{\sqrt t}\Bigg|_1^{+\infty}=2,$$

That is, $\int\limits_1^{+\infty}t^{1/2-2}dt$ converges.

I have two questions:

1. Is my solution valid?
2. Can I avoid substitution $x=\frac1t$ in an example like this? If I hadn't done the substitution, I would've had the following limit:
   $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\tan(x)\ln(1+x)\frac1{\sqrt x}}{x^{2-1/2}}=1.$$
   Without substitution, can the existence of this limit justify the convergence of the given improper integral?

Comment: Why not do the series expansion around $0$? $\tan x\approx x$, $\ln(1+x)\approx x$, so you integrate $1/\sqrt(x)$ around $0$, which is finite

Comment: And using series, you will even get a pretty close approximation of the definite integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution is valid, but you took a circuitous road getting there. When you wrote "Then I saw ...", I'm not sure how you saw it. But it's right.

The thing I saw at the beginning was that $\tan x, \ln (1+x)$ both $\to 0$ as $x\to 0.$ At what rate? Then I remembered both $(\tan x)/x,$ $(\ln(1+x))/x \to 1$ as $x\to 0.$ Why? It follows from the definitions of $\tan'(0),\ln'(1).$ For example,

$$\frac{\tan x}{x} = \frac{\tan x-\tan 0}{x-0}\to \tan'(0)=\sec^2(0) =1.$$

Similar idea for $\ln (1+x).$

So our integrand is

$$\tan x \ln (1+x)\,x^{-5/2} = \frac{\tan x}{x}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}x^{-1/2}.$$

As $x\to 0^+,$ this looks like $1\cdot 1\cdot x^{-1/2}.$ And since $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}\,dx$ converges (to $2$), we have convergence for the original improper integral.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand doing series expansion at 0 (x in v(0) ) at the 1st order
Tan(x)=x+o(x)=x(1+o(1))
Ln(1+x)=x(1+o(1))
In the end, you ll have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$
Obviously it has a finit integral.